# Two persons-rule on MySQL databases for "manual fixes"

Tags: attack-prevention, mysql, iso27001

In order to "harden" our compliance, we wanted to enforce a two-persons rule on the MySQL production database for "manual fixes". Such "manual fixes" frequently arise due to:

- Bug in the application (we are a fast company :D)
- Various customer requests that do not have an application feature implemented yet, such as GDPR update requests, special discounts, etc.

We wanted a process that does not require the two persons to be physically side-by-side. One person is on-call, rather junior and is responsible to translate customer service requests into SQL. They might need a GUI (such as MySQL Workbench) to navigate the complex data model and figure out the exact SQL script to produce. The SQL script should feature `SELECT`s showing the data before and after the change in a non-committed transaction (e.g., `AUTOCOMMIT OFF` no `COMMIT` at the end).

The second person is not on-call, rather senior, and fairly familiar with the application's data model. They should be able to look at the SQL script the non-committed transaction output, and approve or reject via a mobile app during the evening.

We cannot be the first to have this or a similar requirements.

**Does anyone know good documentation or tooling to implement such a process?**

Here are some similar questions on the topic, but not quite as specific as the present one:

- [What can a company do against insiders going rogue and negatively affecting essential infrastructure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131260/what-can-a-company-do-against-insiders-going-rogue-and-negatively-affecting-esse)
- [How can two-man control be implemented efficiently?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/131391/how-can-two-man-control-be-implemented-efficiently)

Comment: Could you explain why you added the [tag:iso27001] tag?

Comment: We see it as implementing A.12.1.2 Change Management.